# Gravatar icon on Company site is wrong

Tags: bug, gravatar, jobs

I'm linked to my company at Stackoverflow's jobs/company site: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/chg-meridian

But my gravatar shown in the "Who you'll work with" section is wrong (any placeholder). Please see my profile on any StackExchange sites to verify that I have an other profile image as shown

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1634225/toni

Comment: Closing this as off topic, since Jobs issues should be reported in Meta Stack Overflow, not in here.

Comment: @rene oh wait..... ignore everything. Found out what's going on. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350567/why-doesnt-my-profile-picture-show-on-my-company-page

Comment: @Tony just enable your Developer story on Stack Overflow and your correct avatar will be imported. (to verify this, look at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/1634225).)

Comment: Thanks @ShadowWizard!

Comment: Cheers, I see you already asked Philipp to do the same. :)